# ASP.net resolve url in css external file

Tags: asp.net, css

I separate the css from the *.aspx file.
When this

```
background-image: url('<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Themes/Red/Images/Contestant/1.jpg)%>';)
```

was in the aspx file it worked, and now it's not working.

do you know any other way ?

Comment: the path in the css file can be relative to its location. E.G. css in "/css/" can refer to "/images/test.jpg" with "../images/test.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

The `scriptlet` and `~` here is specific to aspx file and could not be used in css.

*Change*

```
background-image: url('<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Themes/Red/Images/Contestant/1.jpg)%>';)
```

*To*

```
background-image: url('/Themes/Red/Images/Contestant/1.jpg')
```

*The above assumes the Themes folder is at root your your site.*

To give path relative to `css`

```
background-image: url('Themes/Red/Images/Contestant/1.jpg')
```

Comment: What is relative path of image from root?

Comment: if asp net project hosted in IIS, and is not default but a sub directory, how can the path be programmaticcly set. ASP Net used the ~/ to resolve this, but only works on asp.net pages.

this issue looks to still be the case with visual studio 2013 web projects, and i have not been able to find solution yet, except have to change the css each time i deploy to a new site.

url example would be
http://www.root_site.com/myproject21/images/favicon.png

in css url('/images/favicon.png') we resolve to 
http://www.root_site.com/images/favicon.png 
which is not where it is.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

this is what fix my problem

```
background: url(../../../image.png)
```